# Why is the diode test not working?

Tags: diodes, testing

[image]

I am trying perform a diode test with my digital multimeter. When I measure with the multimeter probe, ([video link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/XnQUxdNvs5UAZKXg6)) I get 0.401 volts in one direction. If I change the location of the probes, it **increases to 1.332 volts** in the other. In the 2nd video ([2. video link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/VAavqeteGsu9EL2R9)), when I take the diode out of the circuit, my measurements seem normal. A constant volt of around 0.553 appears in one direction and ***OL*** in the other direction. I wonder why the diode test on the circuit is not working properly. Which structure connected in parallel to the diode prevents me from taking a healthy measurement?

Comment: Not going to watch the videos, but any other structure in parallel with the diode that has a conductive path will affect the result, so you can (almost) never measure components while they are connected to other components. And you have the black lead in the wrong socket.

Comment: you are so right i forgot

Comment: You plugged the black probe in the wrong jack: it should be in the "COM" jack, not the "A" jack.

Answer (score 2):

> when I take the diode out of the circuit, my measurements seem normal.

Which is to be expected.

But when you test with the diode in circuit you find

> 0.401 volts seen in one direction,... [and] 1.332 volts in the other.

This is because when a component is in a circuit, you are not only testing that component, but also the "rest of the circuit" which is in parallel with the diode.

An example might illustrate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH3nua.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you were to use a diode tester on this circuit, probing between TestPoint1 and TestPoint2, your diode tester would (probably) show only a very small voltage. Why? Because current can flow through the following path.

[image]